# Xcode, iPhone: How to detect simulator target at compile time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I wonder if, when building an iPhone app for the Simulator, there are special DEFINEs added that allow me to conditionally compile for this case?

If not, I'll have to add my own targets for this case, but I'd rather have an automatic way of detection.

Alternatively, is there a dynamic way to know when my code runs on the Simulator, I mean something that's documented? I've been searching the docs for a while now but had no luck yet.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For compile-time check you need TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR defined in TargetConditionals.h

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// Simulator code
#endif
```

For run-time check you can use for example `-model` method in UIDevice. For iPhone simulator it returns `iPhone Simulator` string (not sure about iPad simulator though)

Comment: As of 4.2 when the simulator is in iPad-mode it appears to always return `iPhone Simulator`.

Answer (score 14):

@Update :
 In iOS 9.0 SDK, TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR is - DEPRECATED.
use TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR instead of TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

```
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
  // Simulator code
#endif
```

from Swift 4.1:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    // code for the simulator here
#else
   // code for real devices here
#endif
```